# SQL query between current date and previous week

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT sge_job.j_owner AS "Owner"
      ,SUM(sge_job_usage.ju_cpu) AS "CPU Total"
FROM sge_job_usage, sge_job 
GROUP BY j_owner;
```

Here is my current sql query that just simply reads in CPU% and job owner but I'm having trouble incorporating only sum above if it's between current date say 14days(2 weeks) ago.

In the `sge_job_usage` table belongs both:

`ju_start_time`, `ju_end_time`

Anyone help me towards how I can get it to check if it's between current date - 14 days before and then it checks `end_time` date to see if it was still going then?

`Answer that Outputs What I need below:`

```
SELECT sge_job.j_owner AS "Owner"       
,SUM(sge_job_usage.ju_cpu) AS "CPU Total" 
FROM sge_job_usage, sge_job  
WHERE ju_start_time BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 week' AND LOCALTIMESTAMP 
GROUP BY j_owner;
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the 2 columns? Date, Time, Timestamp?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ADC syntax is not valid for PostgreSQL.

I don't understand which condition do you want to be applied to ju_end_date. But it should be similar to the one on ju_start_time.

```
SELECT sge_job.j_owner AS "Owner"
      ,SUM(sge_job_usage.ju_cpu) AS "CPU Total"
FROM sge_job_usage, sge_job 
WHERE sge_job_usage.C1 = sge_job.C2
  AND ju_start_time BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '14 days' AND LOCALTIMESTAMP
GROUP BY j_owner;
```

I don't have an a test environment so I can't test this but I think it should work.

For more information on the subject check

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Edit: As ypercube as said, you need a join condition on the two tables.

Comment: ah progress, it shows an output now but it's nothing, I've changed the - integer 'say 300' well in the range of what information I have in my DB but nothing is being output in the query except the table headings now, any thoughts on why that could be happening?ju_start_time is set as timestamp without time zone if that could be why?

Comment: I have edited the answer. You should read the link that I posted, it contains valuable information that could help you with your problem.

Comment: It should be `BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '14 days' AND LOCALTIMESTAMP` to show any results.

Comment: thanks for the input you two, have got it showing the desired results now, the answer is displayed under my original question now

Comment: @ypercube, The aim was to either pick the start or the end time, whichever really then get it to go back from current date certain amount of days and see if it was active, Just varied the days and manually calculated what there and it all corellates with what I was after

Comment: OK. Do you also want to count cases where start_time is way long ago (before 14 days ago) and the end_time is after today?

Comment: that could be beneficial, I assume I try your answer below, but I don't full understand the join bit where sge.somecolumn?

Answer (score 5):

I assume the two columns are of the `DATE` type. Then you need something like this:

```
WHERE ju_start_time BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '14 days'
                        AND CURRENT_DATE
  AND ju_end_time >= CURRENT_DATE
```

or this (depending on what condition exactly you want to check:

```
WHERE ( ju_start_time, ju_end_time ) 
      OVERLAPS 
      ( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '14 days', CURRENT_DATE )
```

The query uses 2 tables though and no condition for the Join. It should be:

```
SELECT sge_job.j_owner AS "Owner"
      ,SUM(sge_job_usage.ju_cpu) AS "CPU Total"
FROM sge_job_usage
  JOIN sge_job
    ON sge_job.SomeColumn = sge_job_usage.SomeColumn 
WHERE   ...
GROUP BY j_owner;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you need the same condition for the ju_end_date, but the structure should be:

```
...
WHERE ju_start_time BETWEEN getdate() and DateAdd(d,-14, getdate())
```

Comment: function getdate() saying does not exsist when I try and run my query now? SELECT sge_job.j_owner as "Owner", sge_job_usage.ju_start_time,SUM(sge_job_usage.ju_cpu)as "CPU Total" FROM sge_job_usage, sge_job WHERE ju_start_time BETWEEN getdate() and DateAdd(d, -14, getdate()) GROUP BY j_owner;

Comment: My apologies!! I didn't see the postgre tag: my code is for tsql/sqlserver!!

Comment: This could help: [PostgreSQL date functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html)